# How do I display MySql output as utf-8 instead of latin1?

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

I've been searching for a while and haven't found a good answer for this but....

Is there a way to have my select queries display output in utf-8 instead of whatever the mysql default output is in? I'm 100% positive my data is stored in utf-8 but when I do a select the output I'm given back is a bunch of question marks.

I don't want to change anything in any way I just want my output to display my utf-8 characters properly. Can this be done? Or is this a problem with the terminal? I'm using MySql through a terminal not any MySql gui interface.

Comment: check out this article: http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html/  I know there is php in there but it might help you get closer to the answer.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I had seen similar answers but they all did it through a php function. This article showed me the mysql syntax. For any future reader all you have to do is SET NAMES utf8; and then everything will be displayed in utf8.

Comment: I added it to the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

check out this article: [Turning MySQL data in latin1 to utf8 utf-8](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html/) - I know there is php in there but it might help you get closer to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(_latin1'output' USING utf8);
```